# can we render an array to ajax call directly in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am calling below method in an ajax call. I expect this method to return me an array so that I can loop through in my ajax call for a desired result.

Normally we render partial or text . i am not sure how to render an array. could some one please help me out . I know that render text: for arrays will not work .

```
def get
        @bookmarks = Project.get(params[:username])
        render text: @bookmarks    
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should render it as a JSON object:

```
def get
  @bookmarks = Project.get(params[:username])
  render json: @bookmarks.to_json
end
```